# combineLatest throwing TypeError

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';

const observable_1 = get_first_observable();
const observable_2 = get_second_observable();

console.log('first log', observable_1, observable_2);

observable_1.subscribe(e => console.log('second log', e));
observable_2.subscribe(e => console.log('third log', e));

const combined = combineLatest(observable_1, observable_2);

console.log('fourth log', combined);

combined.subscribe(e => console.log('fifth log', e)); // throws TypeError warning, doesn't work
```

I have a portion of code that behaved just as above, it was working fine until yesterday, when I made some changes to what I thought was unrelated code.

The `first log` confirms that both of these variables are indeed `Observables`.

The `second log` and `third log` confirm that each of observable is emitting at least one value.

The `fourth log` confirms that `combineLatest()` is returning an `Observable` type.

The `fifth log` never fires, and commenting that line out removes the warning. Anywhere I attempt to do `combined.subscribe()` it throws the following TypeError warning.

```
TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

What is going on here?? I have tried everything I can think of to no avail. It seems to me that if I am passing two valid Observables to `combineLatest()`, and they each emit a value, then it should work as expected.

*As requested, the sources of the two observables are as follows:*

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged, map } from 'rxjs/operators';


const get_first_observable = () => {
  const subject = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
  // I am using subject.next(...) elsewhere
  return subject.asObservable().pipe(distinctUntilChanged());
};

const get_second_observable = () => {
  // where store is a redux Store
  const store_subject = new BehaviorSubject(store.getState());
  store.subscribe(() => {
    store_subject.next(store.getState());
  });
  const stream = store_subject.asObservable();

  const my_observable = stream.pipe(
    map(state => {
      return format_data(state) || [];
    })
  );

  return my_observable;
};
```

*Alright, new update.*

This is really strange to me and I don't understand it at all, but I added the line of code below inside `get_second_observable()` before it returns `my_observable`, and then magically all the code works. Now if I comment that line back out it doesn't work anymore.. How does that make any sense? I don't save the new observable to a variable or use it at all. Just combining them seems to make it work down the chain.

```
combineLatest(my_observable, of(true));
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code example. The TypeError is often thrown by *operators* which are attached to the observables, and since you haven't shared how the observables are created, then we can't help you.

Comment: Are you sure that in your actual code, you are importing from 'rxjs' and not 'rxjs/operators'? (that often causes similar errors)

Comment: Yeah, I just double checked and it's coming from 'rxjs', not 'rxjs/operators'. @cgTag I will look into how the observables are created and see if there is an issue there. I didn't post that because it's a lot of code.

Comment: @cgTag I edited the question to provide the sources of each observable (condensed into one function each), does this help? They both seem pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: Please add all imports to your question. Rule of thumb:

All operators - everything that is put into `pipe(...)` - is imported from `rxjs/operators`

Everything else: From `rxjs`.

Comment: @ggradnig as mentioned above, I already triple checked this. each import is coming from the proper place. I will add them to the question though.

Comment: `store.getState()` does this return an observable?

Comment: @cgTag no it's a snapshot of the state. Just an object. see https://redux.js.org/api/store#getState for more details if you need

Answer (score 1):

Changing:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/combineLatest';
```

to:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```

Fixed the error for me:

```
TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

While you already have the proper import, it's possible there is an improper import in code you're not showing. As others have stated, there is no obvious problem with the code you have presented.